# Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 99

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, pandoc

I have deployed my shiny app, and it is properly working on my local computer but when I deployed it to shiny.io, I am receiving this error: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 99. The shiny app generates html report. Here is my Rmarkdown code:
Thanks

````markdown
---
title: "ROC Analysis Report"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: false
    theme: lumen
    highlight: textmate
    class: 'center'
params:
  roc_plot: NA
  roc_table: NA
  chatgpt_interpretation: NA
  chatgpt_interpretationPL: NA
  sales_text: NA
  cl_dist_plot: NA
  cht_int_cls: NA
  pred_dist_plot: NA
  cht_pred_cls: NA
  combined_placeholder: NA
  chatgpt_int: NA
  int_text: NA
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

```
## 1. INTRODUCTION


 

```{r}
params$chatgpt_int
 
```



## 2.RESULTS

```{r}
params$sales_text

```
Note that the after running scispace API, we will enrich this Introduction part.


### Data quality checking

```{r dist-plot, fig.cap="Figure 1: Distribution of biomarker.", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

# The `params` object is available in the document.
plot(params$pred_dist_plot)

```

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$cht_pred_cls


```




```{r, fig.cap="Figure 2: Class distributions of the output.", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

# The `params` object is available in the document.
plot(params$cl_dist_plot)

```


```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$cht_int_cls


```


### ROC plot

```{r, fig.cap="Figure 3: ROC plot of the analysis.", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
plot(params$roc_plot)
```

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$chatgpt_interpretationPL
```

### Performance measures



```{r}
knitr::kable(params$roc_table, caption = "Table 1: Performance measures of the ROC analysis.", format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling()
```


```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$chatgpt_interpretation
```



## 3. CONCLUSION


```{r}
params$combined_placeholder
```
````

Comment: fixed! remove this:  css: styles.css